# How to move decimal?

Tags: javascript, decimal, move

In JavaScript, I want to define where the decimal place goes. I can only really show it in example.

Lets say the input value is `1234`.
I want the output to be `123.4`.

Or, if the input is `12345`, I want the output to be `123.45`.

Or, if the input is `123456`, I want the output to be `123.456`. You get the picture.

To clarify, I just want three digits on the left side of the decimal. The total number of digits is unknown.

So, how could this be done?

Comment: so basically you want the decimal point after the third digit? and do you need this as a string or are you using this for a mathematical operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var n = 1234;
var l = n.toString().length-3;
var v = n/Math.pow(10, l); // new value
```

The `3` is because you want the first 3 digits as wholes, so the base changes depending on the size of `n`.

```
function moveDecimal(n) {
  var l = n.toString().length-3;
  var v = n/Math.pow(10, l);
  return v;
}
```

Try it for 1234, 12345 and 123456.

Answer (score 14):

```
var a = 5007;

// Where `1` below is the amount you want to move it.
a /= Math.pow(10, 1);

document.body.innerHTML = a; // 500.7
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Sdvta/).

Comment: how do you also display the trailing zeros? say you want 5007 to look like 500.70

Comment: @duckx `toFixed()` may do it

Comment: This may work for integers, but not decimal values. There is a loss of precision.  Try:  var a = 0.7;

Answer (score 8):

123456 is 123.456 multiplied by 1000. That means you could move the decimal place over with divisions:

```
var num1 = 1234 / 10;  //sets num1 to 123.4
var num2 = 12345 / 100;  //sets num2 to 123.45
var num3 = 123456 / 1000;  //sets num3 to 123.456
```

Alternatively, if you want to set the number of decimal places in a more general form, you can use the Math.pow function:

```
var num3 = 123456 / Math.pow(10, 3);  //sets num3 to 123.456
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic maths, just divide the number by 10 to move 1 decimal case towards the left side. And multiply by 10 to do the opposite.

"Lets say the input value is 1234. I want the output to be 123.4"

1234 / 10 = 123.4

"Or, if the input is 12345, I want the output to be 123.45"

12345 / 100 = 123.45

Comment: To clarify, i just want three digits on the left side of the decimal.  The total number of digits is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out how many places you want to move the decimal point to the left and divide your number by 10 to the power of that number:

```
123.456=123456/(10^3)
```

Where `^` is raise to the power.

Comment: Javascript does not use the ^ exponent operator.

Comment: @Peter, I think he's giving a numeric equation, not JavaScript.