# Inputting Numbers to Move Across a Decimal Place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to input numbers into a text field and have them pass through the decimal place. I've seen this question - [How to move decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774836/javascript-move-decimal) - and already had code very similar to it. But, I'd like it to read

`$00.00`
after inputing a 1,

`$00.01`, another 1:

`$00.11`, a 2:

`$01.12`, a 231:

`$1122.31`. But I don't want the decimal to move- it should stay in the same place. Is there a name for this? Microwave input?

Comment: Why do you need these troubles? :D

Comment: For a good looking user interface :)

Comment: I don't understand the principle: `1` makes `$00.00`, `another 1` makes `$00.01`, etc...?

Comment: No George, it starts at `$00.00`. When you input a 1, it now reads `$00.01`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's easy man, divide it by 100:

```
function my(n)
{
    var l = n.toString().length;
    var r = n/100;
    //document.write(r); for debugging purpose

    return r;
}
```

I'll add formatting..

**Update:**

```
function mynum(n)
{
    var l = n.toString().length;
    var r = n/100;
    var padded = pad(r, 5, '0'); 
    // I use 5 symbols here because of dot '.' in the number

    return '$' + padded;    
}

function pad(n, width, z) 
{
    z = z || '0';
    n = n + '';
    return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}
```

For pad I used this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073788/3172092

Comment: [why document.write is bad practise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Comment: it was just testing purpose :)

Comment: This looks like it's great, but is there a way to ensure there are at a minimum of 4 figures? So if I ran `my(1)` now it would return `.01` and I would like `00.01`? I know how to ensure figures on the right of a decimal (more precision) but not on the left.

Comment: The problem is in fact, that you added it in _testing purpose_, but people will use it in their code without any doubts. And when someone asks them why do they use this bad thing, they will say: "George Garchagudashvili told us to do it this way" :)

Comment: I we did not use it anytime newbies will never know what it is so :)) Also I assume he has enough knowledge in Javascript, to mention it himself ;)) But I'll comment it don't worry